# Windows 7 update killed iMac 27''

Tags: windows-7, updates, imac

Today (14-Aug-2010) I installed automatic updates for Win7 on my iMac. They could've been there a while waiting to be installed as it was a while since I booted up the mac into Windows. Previous update was on 2-Aug-2010.

Once I restarted the machine, it freezed on the windows startup screen (the logo didn't even come up).

So when I restarted it went into the startup check (find errors or whatever), which - after acknowledging that the system could not restart - just came back with an eloquent:

> could not find a solution for the problem

After that I got a standard (useless) dialog asking to send errors to microsoft (there's only one kind of those that I have ever seen).

So I went into manual restore, which failed for a number of restore points. I was about to despair but then on re-start it worked acknowledging restore for the last restore point I tried.

Now I am afraid to install any further updates. I am guessing that if there is a recent win7 update that causes problems to iMacs 27'' the word should be out by now, so I'd appreciate if anyone has any info on this as I could not find anything on google.

**NOTE**: for those of you picking on my lack of accuracy in describing error messages, my question is more about a recent win7 update that could cause problems to iMac 27''. I don't think there a wide range of possible problems that could affect an iMac 27'' with the last Win7 update and someone must have figured this out before. In this sense, I'd be interested in hearing your experience on that or any relevant advice to the particular situation.

Comment: "the problems could not be fixed, bye bye":

Did it really say bye bye? You should be more exact with what you see with this kind of stuff.

Comment: Obviously not, it just said the problem could not be resolved and prompted me to send a message to MS. The usual stuff, you know.

Comment: "The usual stuff" can vary quite a lot.  Knowing the exact error message would make it more likely that someone can provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: Does the mac side still work?

Comment: Yes - Windows works too after I restored - disabled any updates for now though until I know what to do.

Comment: Actually, it's very relevant. For those of us that understand Windows better than you, we could easily isolate the message as originating from a handful of components and get to the issue at hand.

Comment: @Rafael With this question I just wanted to know if anyone knew anything about a recent win7 update that would cause problem to iMacs. That would narrow it down pretty quick for someone who happens to own an iMac or know anything about it. You're turning it in the usual meta-whining about incorrect error messages, in this case irrelevant. I have to conclude you have nothing better things to do than trolling with arrogance on superuser. Never seen behavior like this on SO.

Comment: @Johnldol - This is how we try to solve things here, if you're not happy about that or cannot respect that way, I urge you to stay on SO...

Comment: @Johnldol With all due respect, most error messages may look like gibberish and useless to the common user, but to techies they have probably seen that error message a million times and know exactly whats wrong. This is why it is VERY import that you post the exact error message. Especially!!! any error codes. (These can usually be found in the event log). Which brings me to my next point, can you check the event log to see if there is anything unusual in there? It may point to a specific update that failed.

Comment: @BloodPhilia Very helpful thanks. I think your attitude is childish to say the least. It's been a good 10 years that I don't get crap like this on a forum.

Comment: @Nathan your comment is probably the 1st one with any informative content, thanks for that. Will try and check out the log and see if I can find something suspicious in there.

Comment: @Nathan also, I get your point about error messages and I am no sysadmin but I think the error message is not the point here. I was looking for feedback from people with iMac that might have figured this out already. I will try to stick to the etiquette next time but I am really surprised about the arrogant attitude of some comments. I am afraid this is not about my question anymore.

Comment: @Johnldol Dude, the only thing that was asked of you was just to include the entire error message? What is your problem!? It isn't that much of a request is it?

Comment: @BloodPhilia that is not much of a request and I would eventually do it if it didn't mean risking that this time around I cannot restore the damn thing, considering that I do believe the error message in this case wouldn't tell you a great deal and the only way to figure this out is to install those damn updates one by one - but I haven't got the time to do that so was just looking for a shortcut here, in case someone else had the same problem. What pissed me off is being called a jackass on twitter [ http://goo.gl/nCF8 ] and being told to go back to SO.

Comment: @Johnldol I'm not calling you a jackass and neither am I telling you to go back to SO... You're more than welcome here, but not all communities are the same... So it was meant as a remark to the fact that you were comparing SU to SO...

Comment: @Johnldol I see... well I hope I didn't make you feel unwelcome anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't encountered a situation like yours before.  I don't run any version of Windows on my Mac computers.

However, if I encountered a problem with a Windows update killing a pc and if I was able to restore the system to a functioning state by reverting changes then I would

- look at the list of pending Windows updates
- research the updates to see if any had specific issues associated with being applied to my particular computer
- apply only those updates that seem to be safe for my particular computer one at a time
- revert any updates that caused a problem and skip those

You should be able to follow the same process updating Windows 7 on an iMac.

I know, it seems like a pain process to go through.  But absent knowing the specific error message you saw the only way to know which update caused your problem is to apply the necessary updates one at a time.

When you have identified the Windows 7 update(s) that cause problems on an iMac, please post an update with your findings.  I'm sure others would appreciate knowing your findings.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks - that sounds reasonable. I can assure you that the only error message I got after the freeze came after the automatic check and was very very generic. I will try to run the updates one by ione and see what happens, but it'll take me time so not sure when I'll be able to get around to do it as I use the machine for work. At the moment I disabled all the automatic updates anyway ...